# python 2 subprocess check_output not returning error output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have this method

```
def do_sh_shell_command(string_command, env_variables=None):
    cmd = shlex.split(string_command)
    try:
       p = subprocess.check_output(string_command, shell=True,
                                   env=env_variables) # shell=True means sh shell used 
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print 'Error running command: ' + '"' + e.cmd + '"' + ' see above shell error'
        print 'Return code: ' + str(e.returncode)
        return e.returncode, e.cmd
    return 0, p
```

which work but for some reason doesn't return the error output from a specfici command

```
def hold_ajf_job(job_order_id):
    #print 'ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF ' + job_order_id + ' HOLD'
    return do_sh_shell_command('ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF ' + job_order_id + ' HOLD')

hold_ajf_job('0e4ba')
do_sh_shell_command('lsl')
```

output:

```
ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF 0e4ba HOLD
Error running command: "ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF 0e4ba HOLD" see above shell error
Return code: 1
/bin/sh: lsl:  not found
Error running command: "lsl" see above shell error
Return code: 127
```

when I run command ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF 0e4ba HOLD just form the normal shell i get the below error output

```
ctmtest1-tctmsv80 [288] ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF 0e4ba HOLD
Failed to Hold Orderno 0000e4ba. (rc=JOBSTATINCM).
```

This is different to the un-useful error output in my python code and I can't for the life of me figure out why?

UPDATE:

Trying stderr=subprocess.STDOUT

```
def do_sh_shell_command(string_command, env_variables=None):
    cmd = shlex.split(string_command)
    try:
       p = subprocess.check_output(string_command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True,
                                   env=env_variables) # shell=True means sh shell used 
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print 'Error running command: ' + '"' + e.cmd + '"' + ' see above shell error'
        print 'Return code: ' + str(e.returncode)
        return e.returncode, e.cmd
    return 0, p
```

output:

```
Error running command: "ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF 0e4ba HOLD" see above shell error
Return code: 1
Error running command: "lsl" see above shell error
Return code: 127
```

Now errors have completely disappeared?

Comment: unrelated: `cmd` is unused in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), when `check_output` raises an exception, it places the output of the command in the `output` attribute of the exception object. You can do the following:

```
try:
    p = subprocess.check_output(string_command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                shell=True, env=env_variables)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
    print 'Error running command: ' + '"' + e.cmd + '"' + ' see above shell error'
    print 'Return code: ' + str(e.returncode)
    return e.returncode, e.cmd
return 0, p
```

Answer (score 0):

By specifying [`stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STDOUT), you can make the output written to standard error to be redirected to standard output.

```
p = subprocess.check_output(
    string_command,
    shell=True,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    env=env_variables)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply falsetru. I have tried that and it seems to remove all my output: see updated in post

Comment: @JustinS, Try `print(p)` after the `subprocess.check_output` call.

Comment: @JustinS, If you just want to let the program output to terminal instead of catching the output, use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call): `subprocess.call(string_command, shell=True, env=env_variables)`